# The named parameter 'pageTransitionsTheme' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, themes, font-family, page-transition, themedata

How to update the following code to the last Flutter version?

```
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
        accentColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        fontFamily: 'Lato',
        pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(
          builders: {
            TargetPlatform.android: CustomPageTransitionBuilder(),
            TargetPlatform.iOS: CustomPageTransitionBuilder(),
          },
        ),
      ),
```

I get the following errors:

> The named parameter 'fontFamily' isn't defined. Try correcting the
> name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named
> parameter with the name 'fontFamily'
>
> The named parameter 'pageTransitionsTheme' isn't defined. Try
> correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining
> a named parameter with the name 'pageTransitionsTheme'.

Also I get another error for this line of the code:

```
color: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.title.color,
```

Error:

> The getter 'title' isn't defined for the type 'TextTheme'. Try
> importing the library that defines 'title', correcting the name to the
> name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
> 'title'.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to share the full code? as a runnable snippet

Comment: Failed to reproduce the issue, everything is  working fine from current snippet